# Tinymce and silex,twig

Tags: twig, tinymce, silex

Hello I would like to use Tinymce with twig but I fail. I don't find the good selector.

My builder form code

```html
<?php

namespace MicroCMS\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextareaType;

class LectureType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('title', TextType::class)
            ->add('content', TextareaType::class,  array(
        'attr' => array(
            'class' => 'tinymce'
        )
    ));
            
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'lecture';
    }
}
```

And now a part of my twig template with tinymce.init. I did not post the whole code to be short.

```html
 {% extends 'layout.html.twig' %}
{% set adminMenu = true %}
{% block javascripts %}
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{asset('/lib/tinymce/tinymce.min.js')}}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        tinymce.init({
            inline : "true",
            selector: ".tinymce"
        });
    </script>
{% endblock %}    
        
        
        <div class="col-sm-6 ">
            {{ form_errors(lectureForm.content) }}
            {{ form_widget(lectureForm.content, { 'attr':  {
                'rows': '8',
            
            }}) }}
        </div>
```